# Laravel - Fastest way to get sum of one column from many results?

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm building a web app, and on this web app the user page displays the user's comment karma (works exactly like reddit, it's basically the sum of the total score of all their comments).

So in my user model I have a function to calculate this:

```
    public function comments()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'created_by', 'id');
    }
    public function commentKarma()
    {
      return $this->comments->where('anonymous', 0)->sum('total_score');
    }
```

However, I'm noticing that in my dev environment (I'm using laravel homestead for reference), this query goes very slow.

So for example, for this user that only has 174 comments, the query is taking up almost 5 seconds.

> select * from `comments` where `comments`.`created_by` = 2 and `comments`.`created_by` is not null
> 4.62s

I don't want to imagine how long this query would take for a user that would have thousands of comments. What would be the best way to speed this up?

I was thinking of maybe setting up a task schedule that would automatically calculate all the users karma every hour or something, but that doesn't seem very optimal either. Thoughts?

Comment: If that's just the database time then what impacts performance is not how many comments the user has is how big the table is overall, since the database needs to scan through all rows to find ones that match the query. Adding an index for `created_by` should help

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->comments->where('anonymous', 0)->sum('total_score');
```

If you only want the sum (meaning the comments relationship is not loaded), this is not a good approach. It will load **every** comment associated with `$this` from the database, Turn them into Eloquent Models, put them into an Eloquent Collection, and finally get the sum from that collection.

If the comments relationship is already loaded, then the following does not apply and maybe adding an index in the comments table might be for the best.

```
return $this->comments()->where('anonymous', 0)->sum('total_score');
```

If you only want the sum, use the query builder to get it. This on the other hand, will only work if total_score is a database column and not an accessor.